# mysql query for table row range

Tags: mysql

This might be a very basic question but I am struggling with queying the specific rows in a table based only on the row range.

Let's say I have a table ABC where I have populated 1000 rows. Now I want a sql query so that I can fetch first 100 rows ( that is the range 1 to 100) and then the next 100 ( 101 to 200) and so on till I am done with all rows. And this should be done without querying/filtering on the table's  id or any column id.

I am not able to figure it out as I am trained only on querying specific columns in WHERE clause so would appreciate if someone can plz help

Comment: To query 100 pseudo random rows, `SELECT * FROM Table1 LIMIT 100`. If you want them to be deterministic, you also need to order by something.

Comment: Thanks, but what is this semi random thing? and how do I keep track of the starting row for my next query

Comment: If you don't order by anything, the rows can come in any order, even different order per query. You can give a second parameter to LIMIT to start at a certain offset, you may want to look it up in the manual.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - Thanks for your suggestions. This gives me a starting point to explore the further, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to use the `LIMIT` clause in the `SELECT` query. MySQL allows you to set two parameters for the clause, the offset (first parameter) and the number of rows to fetch (second parameter).

```
SELECT * FROM `ABC` LIMIT 0, 100
SELECT * FROM `ABC` LIMIT 100, 100
SELECT * FROM `ABC` LIMIT 200, 100
-- etc...
```

However, you cannot guarantee the order of these rows unless you sort by one or more specific column(s) using the `ORDER BY` clause.

Read more about the `SELECT` statement here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html

Answer (score 4):

you can use **limit**  in mysql.

limit accept 2 parameters.

this will return 1-10 records.

```
select * from abcd limit 10
```

this will return 10-20 records.

```
select * from abcd limit 10,10
```

this will return 20-30 records.

```
select * from abcd limit 20,10
```

Comment: There is a significant difference between "20-30 records" (25 +/5 semi-randomly selected records) and "records 20-30" (11 records numbered 20 to 30 inclusive)

Comment: As @WBT pointed out this is still wrong here in 2019. You get records 10 to 20 and not 10 to 20 records.It's even worse, because you actualy get records 10 to 19 (0 based numbering)

Comment: Agree with the other comments "X - Y records" specifies a range of the number of records, hence "10-20 records" sounds like you would get anywhere from 10 to 20 records returned. This is very poorly phrased.